# MS Project How to add manager of Project Owner to view?

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-server-2013

We are using MS Project 2013 for tracking our company's projects. All the RBS (Resource Breakdown Structure) for the users in project server is updated from Human Resources System.

We need to show "**Manager of Project Owner**" in a field. What is the easiest way to show this field?

- Calculated Field ?
- A workflow?
- Or any other method?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason not to use a simple custom text field?

Comment: We can use custom text field which is updated manually, but there are a lot of projects in the system and once the hierarchy changes in HR organization, we should update all these custom fields manually. Is there any quick method for updating these fields? I know web service utility exist in project server but it requires development for calling these services.

Comment: I think you will be doing some development. It may be as easy as generating a simple script to loop through the fields and do a lookup  against the current HR codes. If you don't want to use a web service then just drop the updated HR codes into Excel or Access and grab them from project using VB with OLEDB.

Comment: Thank Eric. I solved the issue using PSI web services and updated a text field with calling these web services.